# Como faço para obter o nome de um botão no MouseListener?

Tags: java, mvc, swing, eventos-do-mouse

Como obtenho o nome de um botão em uma classe que implementa o MouseListener:

```
public class Viewer extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public Viewer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void init(){
        MouseListener ouvinte = new MouseListener();
        btn00.addMouseListener(ouvinte);
    }
}

public class MouseListener implements java.awt.event.MouseListener{

@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        Model modelo = new Model();
        //Como consigo obter o nome do botão "btn00" nesta classe?

        if(modelo.validarJogada(getName(), 1))

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve chamar o método `getSource()` no seu objeto de MouseEvent, ele retornará exatamente o objeto que chamou o método.

É uma boa ideia antes de atribuir esse objeto a uma variável fazer uma verificação se foi mesmo um JButton que chamou ele, pois o `mouseClicked()` pode ser chamado por inúmeros diferentes tipos de componentes, se foi um JButton seu código estará seguro para fazer um cast. Exemplo:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if(me.getSource() instanceof JButton) {    //confere se objeto é do tipo JButton
        JButton b = (JButton) me.getSource();  //faz um cast e atribui a uma variavel
        System.out.println(b.getName());       //chama um método do JButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse b irá armazenar o objeto do botão que chamar o metodo?

Comment: @TuribaMalafaia exato!